# how to hide buttons in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

So, I realize that there are multiple threads asking this type of question, but none of them actually describe the kind of error I'm having.

I create my variables and set my methods in the header here:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *BuildNewTower;
IBOutlet UIButton *CancelTower;

-(IBAction)BuildNewTower:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)CancelTower:(id)sender;
```

I then call these functions in the main class like so:

```
-(IBAction)BuildNewTower:(id)sender{
if(credits >= 15){
    BuildNewTower.hidden = YES;
    CancelTower.hidden = NO;

    Tower1S.hidden = NO;
    Tower2S.hidden = NO;
    Tower3S.hidden = NO;
    Tower4S.hidden = NO;
    Tower5S.hidden = NO;
    }
}

-(IBAction)CancelTower:(id)sender{
BuildNewTower.hidden = NO;
CancelTower.hidden = YES;

Tower1S.hidden = YES;
Tower2S.hidden = YES;
Tower3S.hidden = YES;
Tower4S.hidden = YES;
Tower5S.hidden = YES;
}
```

Roughly summed up, the BuildNewTower and CancelTower buttons do not react to the .hidden variable they inherit. All the other objects (all ImageViews) do disappear like they should.

I'm guessing this might be something about the buttons and them being hidden?

Comment: Have you verified whether the `BuildNewTower` and `CancelTower` ivars are `nil` or not? BTW - Please use proper naming conventions. Variable and method names should always being with lowercase letters. Class names begin with uppercase letters. It's also a bad idea to name your methods exactly the same your outlets. It's confusing.

Comment: I just started out coding in obj-c, so I'm really thankful about your tips! I have checked, yes. Neither of them are nil.

Comment: you can use setHidden instead of .hidden

Comment: its ok if it work then accept it